# Android Calendar time off by 1 hour after converting from GMT to current timezone

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, android-calendar

I am trying to convert a GMT time into my current timezone (which is GMT -7, California to be exact), but it is off by 1 hour behind.

Here is an example of a String that I am retrieving the values from:
`2014-05-07T02:02:04.316Z`

So I am 1 hour short of the correct time (6:02 PM instead of 7:02 PM). Why is this?

```
private Calendar setTimeStamp(String s) {
    int year = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
    int day = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 10));
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(11, 13));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(14, 16));

    Calendar gmtCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    gmtCal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);

    long gmtTimeInMillis = gmtCal.getTimeInMillis();
    long currentTimeInMillis = gmtTimeInMillis + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    Calendar adjustedCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    adjustedCal.setTimeInMillis(currentTimeInMillis);

    return adjustedCal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one hour difference will likely be due to daylight savings. [Clock changes for California](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/san-diego).

However you can refer to the **getDSTSavings()** function in the [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDSTSavings%28%29) class to get the current DST offset for your time zone.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you! Totally forgot about DST /foreheadslap